# How to remove space between two buttons in a table row or "column"?

Tags: html, css, button, spacing

I have the following code. I want to remove the space between the buttons both horizontally and vertically. How to do that?

```
     <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
     <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
     <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>The Main Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table>
            <tr>
                <td><button></button></td>
                <td><button></button></td>
                <td><button></button></td>
                <td><button></button></td>
                <td><button></button></td>
                <td><button></button></td>
                <td><button></button></td>
                <td><button></button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><button></button></td>
                <td><button></button></td>
                <td><button></button></td>
                <td><button></button></td>
                <td><button></button></td>
                <td><button></button></td>
                <td><button></button></td>
                <td><button></button></td>
            </tr>

    </table>

</body>
```

The CSS code is

```
  root 
   { 
     display: block; 
   } 

  button 
   {
     background-image:url('darkSquare.jpg');
     width:50px; 
     height:50px; 
   }
```

[image]

Comment: You might want to check your darkSquare.jpg image to see if the space is in there.

Comment: The image is 60px x 60px

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely being applied by the table itself. By default, a table will have ~3px spacing between cells, plus a padding for each cell (unless you removed them). Try something like this:

```
table { border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0 }
td { padding: 0 }
```

[See the jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/XvSeF/6/)

---

Buttons, by default, also have a border around them which is white on the top and left, and grey on the bottom and right, to create a push effect. They can easily be removed with:

```
button { border: 0 }
```

[See the jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/XvSeF/7/)

Comment: @CodeBlue: Try adding `padding: 0` to the table cell styles.

Comment: Ok, I made the padding zero for td, and now there is only a small amount of whitespace between the buttons.

Comment: @CodeBlue: If you're using both of them, it should work. http://jsfiddle.net/XvSeF/6/

Comment: Ok, that's the same output that I am getting. But there's still the white space right?

Comment: Are you talking about the border around the button? Try adding `button { border: 0 }` and see if that's what you want.

Comment: Shouldn't it be one continuous blob of green such that I cannot see the buttons but see only green throughout?

Comment: Ok! That did it! Thanks so much! Please edit your original reply to include this detail about buttons. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add `border-collapse: collapse` to your `<table>`'s style.

Comment: table
{
    border-collapse: collapse
}


Like this in the CSS? I tried it, but it didn't work.